# how to set android:id in programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to set the `android:id = "@android:id/background"` programmatically.
I try to adapting drawable xml code to java code programmatically.
I wrote other options to code, but couldn't write the `android:id = "@android:id/background"` to code.
here is my code. please let me know the way.

*xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorOrange"/>
            <stroke android:color="#fff" android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale
            android:scaleHeight="10%"
            android:scaleWidth="100%" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
                <solid android:color="@color/colorGreen"/>
                <stroke android:color="@color/colorGreen"
                    android:width="4dp"/>
            </shape>
        </scale>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

*code*

```
        val layer1 = GradientDrawable()
        layer1.cornerRadius = 10f
        layer1.setStroke(1, Color.WHITE)
        layer1.setColor(Color.YELLOW)

        val scaleDrawable =  GradientDrawable()
        scaleDrawable.cornerRadius = 10f
        scaleDrawable.setStroke(1, Color.WHITE)
        scaleDrawable.setColor(Color.BLUE)
        val layer2 = ScaleDrawable(scaleDrawable, Gravity.BOTTOM,1f,0.1f)
        val drawableList = arrayOf(layer1, layer2)
        val layerList : LayerDrawable = LayerDrawable(drawableList)
        this.progressDrawable = layerList
```

*result screen*

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`#layerList.setId`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable#setId(int,%20int)) and set the id by index . Check the code below . I have made few changes in it to match it to `xml-drawable` .

```
val layer1 = GradientDrawable()
layer1.cornerRadius = 10f
layer1.setStroke(1, Color.WHITE)
layer1.setColor(Color.YELLOW)

val scaleDrawable =  GradientDrawable()
scaleDrawable.cornerRadius = 10f
scaleDrawable.setStroke(1, Color.WHITE)
scaleDrawable.setColor(Color.BLUE)

val layer2 = ScaleDrawable(scaleDrawable, Gravity.START,1f,0.1f)
val drawableList = arrayOf(layer1, layer2)
val layerList  = LayerDrawable(drawableList)
layerList.setId(0,android.R.id.background)
layerList.setId(1,android.R.id.progress)
seekBar.progressDrawable = layerList
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I get the same result. Could u give me some advice for this? the blue progress bar still begin at center even though I set the gravity to Gravity.Bottom.

Comment: I used `Gravity.START` and its working fine . i have tested it with Horizontal `Seekbar` . how are you making vertical  seekbar add it with question

Comment: Oh god.. you saved me!! it's working the `Gravity.START`. I'll add the github address when I complete this module! thanks for your help.